# Universal App MySQLConnector Connection error

Tags: c#, mysql, win-universal-app, mysql-connector

I try to use the MySQLConnector to connect on my mysql database on a vserver with phpAdmin. I used different logins to check if the password and the ip is correct and after a view tries i get the

**Error:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
    static string server = "999.999.999.20";
    static string database = "admin_";
    static string user = "root";
    static string pswd = "secret";

    public static void login()
    {
        string connectionString = "Server = " + server + ";database = " 
    + database + ";uid = " + user + ";password = " + pswd + ";"
    +"SslMode=None;";
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
```

The Exception is thrown at "Connection.Open();". The Connection String seems Correct because when I delete SSL Mode or Something else I get the specific Exception. I use the Recerense to MySql.Data.RT

**My Question is:**

What does the Exception mean or what should I specifiy on the Server ?

Comment: Are you using windows 10 ?

Comment: Yes I use windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related with your OS culture and assuming that mysql connector is setting the encoding referencing with OS's culture. Please can you add the encoding directive to your connection string like below;

```
static string server = "999.999.999.20";
static string database = "admin_";
static string user = "root";
static string pswd = "secret";

public static void login()
{
    string connectionString = "Server = " + server + ";database = " 
    + database + ";uid = " + user + ";password = " + pswd + ";"
    +"SslMode=None;"
    +"CharSet=utf8;";
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
```

PS: The encoding on your database is important, I assume you are using UTF8

Comment: did you have a link or tutorial because now I stack on the execution ?

Comment: @SeeuD1 what you mean ? Whats the problem with execution ?

Comment: I try to execute a queue but at the execution:"using (MySqlDataReader reader = checkLogin.ExecuteReader())" I get the Exception "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in MySql.Data.RT.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Connection must be valid and open." The connection is open

Comment: @SeeuD1 oh I get it, you may ask a new question about that issue and providing your full code in your question will return you as a best result. I assume that `connection.Open();` is not throws an Exception.

Comment: done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108468/universal-app-mysqlconnector-queue-execution-error