# Universal App MySQLConnector Queue execution error

Tags: c#, mysql, win-universal-app, mysql-connector

I try to Execute a queue to my database on my vserver with PHPAdmin and i get the

**Exception:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
        static string server = "999.999.999.235";
    static string database = "admin_";
    static string user = "root";
    static string pswd = "secret";

    public static void login()
    {
        string connectionString = "Server = " + server + ";database 
        = "+ database + ";uid = " + user + ";password = " + pswd + ";" + "SslMode=None;" + "CharSet=utf8;";
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new 

    MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand checkLogin = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `UserData`;");
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = checkLogin.ExecuteReader())
            {
                reader.Read();
                string hash = reader.GetString("UserName");
                string salt = reader.GetString("Workbench");
```

The Exception is thrown at:

**MySqlCommand checkLogin = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `UserData`;");**

I tried it with `UserData` and UserData with and without ; same Exception. On the Server the Queue is working fine.

**Question:**
Is the queue wrong or do I forget a configuration on the server ?

Comment: could you give me the link for Mysql DLL file that you have used?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-installation-binary-mysql-installer.html here is also the tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was, that I forgot to set the connection for the command

```
connection.Open();
MySqlCommand checkLogin = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `UserData`",connection);
```

After adding the connection, all is working fine.